# How to modify the log4j access patterns as per requirements(ResultCode,ResponseTime,RemoteHOST)

Tags: log4j, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using wso2 esb-4.8.1
I wish to use my own log4j pattren basically my proxy service will create there own log file which need contain some specific information that i have done using this blog [enter link description here](http://dakshithar.blogspot.in/2012/03/logging-with-wso2-esb.html)

this configuration has been done

```
log4j.category.SERVICE_LOGGER.PROXY_TEST=INFO, PROXY_APPENDER
# log4j.additivity.PROXY_APPENDER=false
log4j.additivity.SERVICE_LOGGER.PROXY_TEST=false
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER=org.wso2.carbon.logging.appenders.CarbonDailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2-esb-PROXY_TEST_Proxy${instance.log}.log
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.Append=true
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.layout=org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern= [%T]  [%t] %a %5p %c{1} %m %n
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.layout.TenantPattern=%U%@%D [%T] [%S]
log4j.appender.PROXY_APPENDER.threshold=DEBUG
```

And the file is creating in location but I wish to capture the 
ResultCode,RemoteHost,ResponseTime  for that i have added in my pattren

**%a - Remote IP address**
**%T - Time taken to process the request, in seconds**
But while I am starting wso2 ESB server getting this errors
like

```
log4j:ERROR Unexpected char [a] at position 8 in conversion patterrn.
log4j:ERROR Unexpected char [T] at position 23 in conversion patterrn.
```

In my file printing like this pattren

```
**[0]**  [localhost-startStop-1] **%a**  INFO PROXY_TEST Building Axis service for Proxy service : PROXY_TEST 
[0]  [localhost-startStop-1] **%a**  INFO PROXY_TEST Adding service PROXY_TEST to the Axis2 configuration 
**[0]**  [localhost-startStop-1] **%a**  INFO PROXY_TEST Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : PROXY_TEST 
**[0]**  [PassThroughMessageProcessor-1] %a  INFO PROXY_TEST To: /services/PROXY_TEST, WSAction: http://www.openuri.org/clientRequest, SOAPAction: http://www.openuri.org/clientRequest, MessageID: urn:uuid:7853a5ed-e4d4-4b4b-ac72-c111ab44280d, Direction: request,
```

Why I am getting like this even i tried with request and response but my rersponse time and REMOTE HOST is not printing .
Is wso2 will support this r not.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in your configuration the class `org.wso2.carbon.utils.logging.TenantAwarePatternLayout` is doing the pattern handling. It is a subclass of `org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout`. Both do not know the placeholder %a. The placeholder %T however should be treated as tenant-ID.

To solve your problem yoy have to write your own pattern layout class (best extending TenantAwarePatternLayout) and handle there the new placeholders you need.